# Failed to capture a certain portion of text out of a long text using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to scrape a portion of text out of a long text using regex.

Original text: `If you have any questions or concerns, you may contact us at kaieldentsome [!at] gmail.com. You can also follow us on fb`

Portion I'm interested in: `kaieldentsome [!at] gmail.com.`

It's not necessary that `contact us at` will always be present there.

I've tried with:

```
import re

item_str = 'If you have any questions or concerns, you may contact us at kaieldentsome [!at] gmail.com. You can also follow us on fb'
output = re.findall(r"(?<=\s).*?\s\[!at\].*?\s.*?\s",item_str)[0]
print(output)
```

Output I wish to get:

```
kaieldentsome [!at] gmail.com.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<=\s)\S+\s\[!at\]\s\S+\.\S+
```

- `(?<=\s)` Positive lookbehind, assert a whitespace char to the left
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\s\[!at\]\s` Match `[!at]` between whitespace chars
- `\S+\.\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars with at least a dot

Note that there has to be a whitespace to the left present. If that is not mandatory, you can omit `(?<=\s)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGy99z/1)

Comment: The lookbehind is redundant IMO.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg It depends on if that is a requirement, but you can omit it if not.

Answer (score 1):

```
\S+\s*\[!at\]\s*\S+
```

Will also work if there is no whitespace before and/or after the `[!at]`.

If you want to exclude the trailing `.`, you can do this:

```
(\S+\s*\[!at\]\s*\S+)\.?
```

Then take the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is usually greedy. Meaning it will match as much as possible. So by using `.*`, it'll match all characters, including whitespaces.

If you use `\S*` instead, which will match everything, except for whitespaces, you will get the desired result.

Updated code:

```py
import re

item_str = 'If you have any questions or concerns, you may contact us at kaieldentsome [!at] gmail.com. You can also follow us on fb'
output = re.findall(r"(?<=\s)\S*?\s\[!at\]\S*?\s\S*?\s",item_str)[0]
print(output)
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/ZMw139/1

Comment: I don't think `\S*` is the way to go. That would match zero or more non-spaces. The email address must contain at least one character before and after the `@`.

Comment: It depends on the OPs requirements.